# JavaFX Drag View for Transparent png image

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag an Object which is represented as PNG image with transparent background from an AnchorPane to an HBox.

I set the image to the Drag View with this lines:

```
        SliderItemHandler mh = (SliderItemHandler) event.getSource();
        Dragboard db = mh.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
        db.setDragView(mh.getModule().getImage());
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        db.setContent(content);
```

It is all fine with nontransparent background images, but with the transparent ones the image got a white background with opacity "0.8" i think.

I tried taking a snapshot for the node:

```
        db.setDragView(mh.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null));
```

but it didn't work, the white background still there.
Is there any other way to make it transparent like the original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure how you achieve to get a white background, taking the opacity into account. However, I re-created your use case and will show you how I implemented this.

The following image is a `Scene` divided between an `AnchorPane` on the left, and a `HBox` on the right. The small transparent circle being the source `ImageView` to copy, the larger circle next to it being a dropped `Image` and far-most right being a circle currently being dragged. *(Screenshot didn't include the cursor.)*

[image: Drag]

As you can see, in none of the 3 scenarios there is a white (or almost white) background. It is just the image itself, with the image itself being a bit more transparent while dragging.

To achieve this, we'll take 2 variables into account. The source `ImageView` and the destination `HBox`.

```
@FXML
private HBox destination;
@FXML
private ImageView image;
```

We'd like the image to be dragged, so we add a `DRAG_DETECTED` event onto the `ImageView`.

```
image.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED, mouseEvent -> {
    Dragboard db = image.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putImage(image.getImage());
    db.setContent(content);
    mouseEvent.consume();
});
```

Then we'd like the destination `HBox` to accept the dragged `ImageView`.

```
destination.addEventHandler(DragEvent.DRAG_OVER, (DragEvent event) -> {
    if (event.getDragboard().hasImage()) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
    }
    event.consume();
});
```

And of course we'd like to place the `ImageView` into the `HBox` when actually dropped. In this case, it just places a copy of it into the `HBox`, but that's open for implementation of course.

```
destination.addEventHandler(DragEvent.DRAG_DROPPED, (DragEvent event) -> {
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    destination.getChildren().add(new ImageView(db.getImage()));
    event.setDropCompleted(true);
    event.consume();
});
```

That's all there is to dragging and dropping an image. No white backgrounds involved for transparent images. However, if you're able to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it might be easier to look into your problem if it still maintains.

Comment: i changed 'db.setDragView' to 'content.putImage' and the drag image is transparent again. I don't know what is the difference but it works good.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your snapshot parameters to transpartent fill:

```
SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
sp.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
db.setDragView(mh.snapshot(sp, null));
```

The result will be transparent without the white borders.